# Checking Value against range of values to return item type and may need to go return item from next row down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of diameters and fasteners.  There are 4 columns: Min Dia, Max Dia, Fast Type, Fastener.  I want to use the Incoming Diameter from another table to return the Fastener based on the min and max diameters.  Is there a way to check the incoming diameter against the min and max diameters to return the fastener if the incoming diameter falls within the min and max range and when the incoming diameter is greater than the max diameter, return the fastener from the next row down?  I don't know if this can be done without VBA.

If my incoming diameter is 0.1520, I would want to have "A" returned.  If the incoming diameter is 0.1600, I would want "B" returned.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: But `0.1600` does not seem to appear in the min-max range?

Comment: 0.1600 is the incoming diameter from in input table.  Hole sizes don't always come in neat, specific sizes, so I need to know if I need to go up to another size for the repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

```
=INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(D2:D4)/((F2>=A2:A4)*(F2<=B2:B4)),ROW(D2:D4)/(F2<=A2:A4)),1))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

**Edit**

Formula syntax for Excel tables:

```
=INDEX(Table2[[#All],[fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(Table2[fastener])/(([@diameter]>=Table2[min])*([@diameter]<=Table2[max])),ROW(Table2[fastener])/([@diameter]<=Table2[min])),1))
```

[image]

Comment: I get both #REF! and #VALUE! errors with this code, granted that not all the inputs have been added yet.  My input table is on one worksheet and my fastener database table is on another sheet.  I'm not sure if that is causing the errors or the fact that my data is in tables or something else entirely.  The code I have now is (sorry its messy): `=INDEX(Table7[Fastener],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(Table7[Fastener])/(([Incoming Dia]>=Table7[Dia Min])*([Incoming Dia]<=Table7[Dia Max])),ROW(Table7[Fastener])/([Incoming Dia]<=Table7[Dia Min])),1))`

Comment: @Piseagan your formula looks OK, except array argument of ```INDEX``` function - try changing it to ```Table7[[#All],[Fastener]]```. And don't forget that it is array formula. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365 and have the `XLOOKUP` function, you can use:

```
=XLOOKUP(A10,$B$2:$B$4,$D$2:$D$4,,1,1)
```

[image]